# CSS FLOAT LEFT - can't get two divs next to eachother

Tags: html, css

Have checked several similar answers and tried different things with wrappers, absolute/relative and so on and so on. Can't seem to make my divs do what I want..! :-)

Here's the situation:

```
<div id="slideout">
        <div id="slidecontent" style="margin:20px;float:left;">
           TEXT
        </div>
        <div id="clickme" style="width:300px;float:left;background: #FFF;" align="right">
            <img src="img/xxx.png" style="padding:2px;" width="16" height="15">
        </div>
    </div>
```

The not-inline css is this (made som inline adjustments for test...):

```
#slideout {
    z-index: 200;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 60%;
    top: 20%;
    left:-280px;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
    opacity:0.75;
}

#clickme {
    z-index: 200;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #000;
}

#slidecontent {
}
```

What I want: the wrapper "slideout" is absolute, because it is placed in the left part of the screen and slides out with some jQuery code. Then I would like the two divs placed next to eachother in stead of on top of eachother...

Comment: Can't really understand, what would you like to do? The `#clickme` element should be visible and `#slidecontent` not. When user hovers the `#slideout`, the `#slideout` should slide and `#slidecontent` appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `slideout` has `width:300px`.
Your `clickme` has `width:300px`.

There's no room left to put anything next to it!

Try removing `width:300px` from `clickme`.

Answer (score 2):

set the width of both div equally to the parent div. i.e 150+150 or so

```
<div id="slideout">
        <div id="slidecontent" style="margin:20px;float:left;width:150px;">
           TEXT
       </div>
        <div id="clickme" style="width:150px;float:left;background: #FFF;" align="right">
           <img src="img/xxx.png" style="padding:2px;" width="16" height="15">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should explain *what* you changed, and *why*.